# Closed form of $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n dx}{1+(x+a)^b}\,dx $ with $b \gg 1$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I've been trying to get the result of the integral

$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+\left(x+a\right)^b}\, dx $$

as an aproximation to the Fermi integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{e^{\beta(x-\mu)} + 1}\, dx $$

Which is a type of integral that appears in quantum statistics of gases in statistical mechanics.

If it's helpful to reach a solution, I'm interested in the result of the integral when $b \gg 1$ $a<1$, and $n$ is a fractional power and is on the order of 1.

Following a solution to the integral,
$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1 + x^b}\, dx $$
I've tried contour integration using a pizza slice with the tip starting at the first pole of the function but haven't been successful. One of the integrals of the contour has the form:
$$ \int_0^\infty \dfrac{(y-a)^{n}}{1+y^b}\, dx $$

and the fact that $n$ is a fractional power did not allow me to factor $a$ out of the integral.

Comment: The limits and the form of the integrand suggest that a keyhole contour (and possibly integrating against $\log z$) could be more helpful than a "pizza-slice" contour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see. I had been copying the method for integrating $ x^n/(1+x^m)$ which used  a pizza slice, thats why. What would it mean integrate against log$z$? Thanks!

Comment: That same technique won't work here: The values of $1 + z^m$ are the same along rays from the origin an angular distance, e.g., $\frac{2\pi}{m}$ apart, but the same is not true after shifting.

Comment: By integrating a function $f(x)$ against $\log$, I mean evaluate $\int_\ast^\ast f(z) \log z \,dz$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the post is closed - I cannot post the solution. But if this helps, for $n>-1$ and $a\in[0;1)$
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+\left(x+a\right)^b}\, dx\sim\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{(1-a)^{n-1}(1-a+n)}{b^2}\frac{\pi^2}6+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)$$
and for $n>-1$ and $a>1$
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+\left(x+a\right)^b}\, dx\sim a^{n+1-b}\Gamma(n+1)\left(\frac{\Gamma(b-n-1)}{\Gamma(b)}+O(a^{-b})\right)$$
If, additionally, $b\gg n^2$, for $n>-1$ and $a>1$
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+\left(x+a\right)^b}\, dx\sim 
\frac{a^{n+1-b}\Gamma(n+1)}{b^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain how you get to the first series?

Comment: Yes, I can, but it requires some space, and it is not convenient (and, I guess, not appropriate) to post the whole solution in the comment. In my opinion, the best option is to reopen the question (probably, it is possible if you edit question, adding some additional information: the context, your efforts, your ideas).

Comment: I've edited and sent for revision. I'm particularly interested in the first series as it appears similar to the solution using other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the nice general solution by @Claude Leibovici we can add asymptotics at $b\to\infty$. Let's consider the case $a\in[0;1); n>-1$.
$$I=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+\left(x+a\right)^b} dx=\int_a^\infty\frac{(x-a)^n}{1+x^b}dx=\int_{\ln a}^\infty\frac{(e^t-a)}{1+e^{bt}}dt$$
$$=\frac1b\int_{b\ln a}^\infty\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb}{1+e^t}dt=\frac 1b\int_{b\ln a}^0\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb}{1+e^t}dt+\frac 1b\int_0^\infty\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb}{1+e^t}dt=I_1+I_2$$

Next,
$$I_1=\frac 1b\int_{b\ln a}^0\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb}{1+e^t}dt=\frac 1b\int_{b\ln a}^0(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tbdt-\frac 1b\int_{b\ln a}^0\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb}{1+e^t}e^tdt$$
$$=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac1b\int_0^{-b\ln a}\frac{(e^{-\frac tb}-a)^ne^{-\frac tb}}{1+e^{-t}}e^{-t}dt$$
$$=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac1b\int_0^{b\ln \frac1a}\frac{(e^{-\frac tb}-a)^ne^{-\frac tb}}{1+e^t}dt$$
The first term is trivial:

at $b\to\infty\,\, (x+a)^b\to 0 \,\,\text{at}\,x<1-a \,\,\text{and}\,\,(x+a)^b\to\infty \,\,\text{at}\,x>1-a \,\,$, so we get the "Fermi's step",  taking the interval of integration $[0;1-a]$.

For the second term we can extend the interval of integration $\to \infty$. We don't have to worry about the meaning $(e^{-\frac tb}-a)^n \,\,\text{at}\,\,e^{-\frac tb}<a$ - due to the factor $\frac1{e^t+1}$ all these additional terms will have the order $\sim a^b$ and are, therefore, exponentially small.

Hence, dropping exponentially small corrections,
$$I=I_1+I_2\sim\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac1b\int_0^\infty\frac{(e^\frac tb-a)^ne^\frac tb-(e^{-\frac tb}-a)^ne^{-\frac tb}}{1+e^t}dt$$
We notice that at $t\sim\sqrt b\quad\frac tb\sim\frac1{\sqrt b}\ll1$; at the same time $\frac1{e^t+1}\sim e^{-\sqrt b}\ll1$. It means that we are allowed to decompose the nominator into the series: $e^\frac tb=1+\frac tb+...$ We see that all even powers of $t$ are dying out.
$$I= \frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac1b\int_0^\infty\frac{(1-a+\frac tb)^n(1+\frac tb)-(1-a-\frac tb)^n(1-\frac tb)+O(\frac1{b^3})}{1+e^t}dt$$
$$=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{(1-a)^n}b\int_0^\infty\frac{(1+\frac t{b(1-a)})^n(1+\frac tb)-(1-\frac t{b(1-a)})^n(1-\frac tb)+O(\frac1{b^3})}{1+e^t}dt$$
$$=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{2(1-a)^n(\frac n{1-a}+1)}{b^2}\int_0^\infty\frac t{e^t+1}dt+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}+\frac{(1-a)^{n-1}(1-a+n)}{b^2}\frac{\pi^2}6+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)\,\,}\tag{1}$$
This approach allows to evaluate as many terms of the decomposition as we want. It is also interesting to check the answer, for example, for the case $a=0$.

On the one hand, we have from (1)
$$I(a=0)=\frac1{n+1}+\frac{\pi^2(n+1)}{6b^2}+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)$$
On the other hand,
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x^b} dx=\frac1b\int_0^\infty\frac{t^\frac nbt^\frac{1-b}b}{1+t}dt\overset{x=\frac1{1+t}}{=}\frac1b\int_0^1(1-x)^{\frac{n+1}b-1}x^{-\frac{n+1}b}dx$$
$$=\frac1bB\left(\frac{n+1}b;1-\frac{n+1}b\right)=\frac1b\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}b\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{n+1}b\right)$$
$$=\frac\pi b\frac1{\sin\frac\pi b(n+1)}=\frac1{n+1}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}6\frac{(n+1)^2}{b^2}+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac1{n+1}+\frac{\pi^2(n+1)}{6b^2}+O\left(\frac1{b^4}\right)$$

Comment: That's impressive. Thank you for all the work! Can i ask how do you come up with the idea to turn $x$ into exponentials in the first few steps?

Comment: @hernandez.hdd  Thank you. Regarding the substitution - this is a natural step: as soon as we get $x^b, b\to\infty$, the substitution $x=e^t$ usually works.

Answer (score 2):

Using algebra, assuming $a>0$ and $b>m+1$

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+(x+a)^b} \,dx=\int_{-a}^\infty \frac{(t-a)^n}{1+t^b}\,dt $$
$$\int_a^\infty \frac{t^m}{1+t^b}\,dt=\frac 1{m+1}+(-1)^m \frac {a ^{m+1}}{m+1}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{m+1}{b};\frac{b+m+1}{b};-(-a)^b\right)$$

If $b\to \infty$, the Gaussian hypergeometric function goes to $1$ and we are left with the binomial expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clarify how you go from $(t-a)^n$ to $t^m$? I'm not sure how you get rid of the $-a$.

Comment: @hernandez.hdd. The $t^m$ will appear in the bnimial expansion of $(t-a)^n$